# append three excel sheet's data with same header in R

Tags: r

The data.xlsx contains three sheet S1,S2,S3. All of them use the same header, how to merge these data into one data frame?

data.xlsx S1 sheet

```
A B C
a1 b1 c1
```

data.xlsx S2 sheet

```
A B C
a2 b2 c2
```

data.xlsx S3 sheet

```
A B C
a3 b3 c3
```

Here is my starting code

```
s1 = read.xlsx('data.xlsx', sheetName='S1')  # contains 2 rows
s2 = read.xlsx('data.xlsx', sheetName='S2')  # contains 3 rows
s3 = read.xlsx('data.xlsx', sheetName='S3')  # contains 4 rows
all = s1 + s2 + s3 # of cause this is wrong code
```

I wish the **all** contains

```
A B C
a1 b1 c1
a2 b2 c2
a3 b3 c3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this

```
rbind(s1,s2,s3)
```

this assumes s1 ,s2 and s3 has same no of cols